# How to configure Apache for PHP on Windows 7?

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache 2.0(httpd-2.0.64-win32-x86-no_ssl) and it works, then I have installed Php5.3 and it pointed to Apache configuration folder.

> > failed scenario:
> >       1- create simple test.php, put in under C:\Apache\Apache2\htdocs
> >       2- call "http://localhost:8080/test.php"  --> "Bad Request..Your browser sent a request     that this server could not understand."
> >
> > Proposed solution by NetBeans blog (failed)
> >     1-add those two lines to httpd.conf
> >      AddType Application/x-httpd-php .php 
> >      LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/sapi/php5apache2_2.dll"
> >     It doesnt works because there is no "php5apache2_2.dll" under my Php installation folder??
> >     I have such .dll : php5ts.dll, ssleay32.dll,..

Any one have any suggestion in order to run the PHP script successfully?

Comment: You can try running PHP as a CGI script. http://windows.fyicenter.com/view.php?ID=68 Maybe FastCGI?

Comment: This was migrated to ServerFault, however, as it is about configuring developer tools on a client OS it is off topic for us. If the people who closed this off topic read the [faq] then it clearly states that developer tools are on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easiest to just download [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or a [similar all-in-one web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs), especially since your environment is most likely not a production environment.

Comment: Manually installing Apache and PHP is a fun thing to do, but judging by the question, this person wants a development server that *just works*.

Answer (score 0):

Just download `php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.3-win32.zip` from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

[Here](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/) is a guide how to configure your apache to work with PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you asked for but why to use WAMP? First of all it's not a good idea to integrate you desktop with DEV environment (it gets messy quickly). Windows is not a natural environment for web application.

Get yourself a [VMWare player](http://www.vmware.com/uk/products/desktop_virtualization/player/overview.html) (it's free) and install Ubuntu Server on it. Now you can work from Windows on your Linux server. You can also get your VMWare environment home if required.

Comment: Why not to buy dedicated server with Gentoo then? :)

Comment: "buy" is the keyword here, Gentoo? Do you really want to compile everything for a sake of doing it on a DEV environment?